# Combination With Limitations

Tags: combinatorics

> I have read the following example from Sheldon Ross book:
>   
>   Consider a set of n antennas of which m are defective and n − m are functional and assume that all of the defectives and all of the functionals are considered indistinguishable.
>   
>   How many linear orderings are there in which no two defectives are
>   
>  consecutive?

The solution offered is to place from the $(n-m+1)$ spaces between the already placed non-defectives antennas so it is ${n-m+1 \choose m}$.

For sake of learning I am trying to count all the possibilities and reduce  those how are not allowed.

So there are  ${n \choose (n-m)!m!}$ combination to order the antennas, now I have to recuded all the combinations that have more than 1 defective antennas in a row, How should I continue?

Comment: you wrote $\binom{n}{(n-m)!m!}$ which is more than likely equal to zero (by definition $\binom{n}{r}=0$ whenever $r>n$ or $r<0$).  Surely you mean to say $\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}$ instead?  The easiest solution is already given above by your book (lay out the nondefectives with empty spaces inbetween in a line and then put the defectives inbetween or to the far left or right, no more than one per space).  Another way of thinking of it, breaking it into cases, either the furthest right is defective or not, and temporarily gluing a nondefective to the right of each defective.

Comment: Approaching via inclusion-exclusion for this problem is ill-advised and will be very tedious (if not almost impossible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on approaching this via inclusion-exclusion, then define the following sequence of events:

Let $A_i$ denote the event that the $i^{th}$ and the $(i+1)^{st}$ antennae are both defective.  As such, $A_i^c$ is the event that the $i^{th}$ and the $(i+1)^{st}$ antennae have at most one defective antennae.

So, we are interested in counting $|A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap A_3^c\cap \dots \cap A_{n-1}^c|$, i.e. the number of outcomes in which there are no two consecutive defective antennae.

By inclusion-exclusion, this becomes:

$|S|-|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup \dots \cup A_{n-1}| = |S| - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} |A_i| + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n-1}|A_i\cap A_j| - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{k=j+1}^{n-1}|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k| + \cdots = |S| + \sum\limits_{\Delta\subseteq[n-1],\Delta\neq \emptyset}(-1)^{|\Delta|}|\bigcap\limits_{i\in\Delta} A_i|$

To calculate, say $|A_1\cap A_2|$, that is "the first and second are defective *and* the second and third are defective," it will be $\binom{n-3}{m-3}$, whereas $|A_1\cap A_3|$ is "the first and second are defective *and* the third and fourth are defective" gives $\binom{n-4}{m-4}$.

Simplifying this expression is doable given a specific value for $n$ and $m$, however it is not readily apparent how to simplify the expression for arbitrary $n$ and $m$.

The ideal solution is as mentioned in the books and my comments above, to take advantage of the fact that we want no two defectives adjacent and utilize the non-defectives as barriers.